# How do I get directory structure in a single call to the filesystem?

Tags: c#, .net, file, vsto

I have a VSTO application that browses a directory and lists subfolders and files in an excel sheet in a certain format. I currently use `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` but it takes a long time to process. The directory is on a network share. It appears that every enumeration on `GetFiles` or `GetDirectories` is a separate call to the filesystem. I am actually only interested in the directory structure under a certain folder. I just want to extract the names and paths of subfolders and files. is there a certain way to retrieve a complete overview of this structure in a single call to the filesystem? What are my options?

**edit:**

I am using .NET 4.0

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: If I remember correctly there is no way to get a quick directory listing. I'd start searching here http://pinvoke.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall that there's anything that will get your entire tree in one call.

I know that this isn't the complete solution to your problem, but you can enumerate through your directories and files while they are still loading using [EnumerateDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413235.aspx) and [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232.aspx).  Unfortunately, this doesn't reduce *total* load time, but often the appearance of progress will reduce the pain of waiting.

Comment: I ended up making a progress bar. I don't have time for a lot of research. This is only an in-house project.

Answer (score 0):

in all drives all directories c#

```
    public List<DirectoryInfo> getDirectoryStructure()
    {
        List<DirectoryInfo> drives = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
        string[] drives = System.Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
        foreach (string dr in drives)
        {
            System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo(dr);

            // Here we skip the drive if it is not ready to be read. This
            // is not necessarily the appropriate action in all scenarios.
            if (!di.IsReady)
            {
                continue;
            }
            drives.Add( di.RootDirectory);
        }
        return drives
    }
```

to find a specific dir enumerate recursevly over the subdirs.